# Declare a type in TypeScript that denotes the empty set

Tags: typescript

I know a little about TypeScript which I've learned this month in a university course.

Can this denote the empty set?

```
type emptySet=0&1;
```

because when I try to assign this to any value, i.e. (boolean, number, string) I get type error.

I'm not sure what 0&1 does in typescript, in other programming languages, This denotes "false" or a bitwise operation.

Comment: Can you show a usecase? I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to acheive here.

Comment: That's a theoretical question in HW. I think a type which does not accept any value can define the empty set. The type 1&0 which I'm not sure what does it define in terms of values, fits since it does not accept anything in reality

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but this is valid and would mean "empty set" as nothing can be void

```
type EmptySet = void[];

const empty: EmptySet = []; // valid
const notEmpty: EmptySet = [1,2,3]; // not valid
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to redirect the question: before I was asked about giving an example of a finite set of 5 elements.  Type a=1|2|3|4|5 seems as a legit answer. So in the same manner, I think that 1&0 can define a set which accepts nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The type that accepts nothing is `void`.

```
type emptySet = void;

let es: emptySet = null;
```

There is also the `never` type, which doesn't accept anything, even `null`.

```
type emptySet = never;

let es: emptySet = null; // Error
```